# RPM Build returns 1 on Cygwin

Tags: maven, cygwin, rpm, rpmbuild

I am using Cygwin to run a `mvn package` on some code I was provided. I definitely can't change anything about the provided code, so I know something is wrong on my end.

I installed `rpm` and included the `cmd.exe` path as necessary, but am still running into errors.

Here is the log error I get at the end

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.2:attached-rpm (generate-rpm) on project XXX: RPM build execution returned: '1' executing 'cmd.exe /X /C "rpmbuild -bb --target "noarch-pc-windows 7" --buildroot XXX --define "_topdir XXX" XXX.spec"' -> [Help 1]
```

- I replaced some private information with XXX. If you need to know what XXX represents, please let me know.

Comment: You know this environment is supported? Is that the entirety of the log relating to the error?

Comment: I honestly am not sure. How well supported is RPMbuild on Cygwin

Comment: No earthly idea. Nor do I know how well the maven rpm builder supports it or how well the project you are building supports it (assuming the other pieces support it).

Comment: I have worked quite a bit with the rpm-maven-plugin, and from my experience it is better to build the package under a virtual machine. While it is relatively easy to deal with RPM's `autoreqprov` feature, defining the correct manual dependencies can be a pain in the neck. Also note that RPM based distributions tend to have subtle differences - a .rpm  build for Red Hat may install on an OpenSuSE, wether it runs correctly may well be a whole different story. Furthermore, you should do some smoke testing with the new packages under the target OS, requiring at least VMs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That may be happening because you don't have all the necessary packages installed.

To run `rpm-maven-plugin` in Cygwin you will need these packages installed:

- rpm
- rpm-build
- rpm-devel

Also make sure that %CYGWIN_HOME%\bin is in `PATH` environment variable.